# Problemas cerrando un modal al cambiar un div de contenido

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, modal

Buenas tardes tengo un modal en el cual muestro una lista de indicadores que están relacionados a un indicador previamente seleccionado.
Le cree una función de javascript para que al seleccionar una opción de esta lista oculte el modal y cambie el div de mi pagina con el contenido seleccionado.

la función es la siguiente:

```
function ocualtar(div, page) {

$("#miModal").modal('hide');  //ocultamos el modal

$(div).load(page, function (data, status, xhr) {  //aquí hago el cambio en el div 
    if (status == "error") {
        $("#errorPrincipal").html(data + "<br/>" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    } else {
        //$(div).html(data);
        finalizar();
    }
}); }
```

mi problema ocurre que todo lo hace bien a excepcion de que la pantalla se queda en negro pero se puede visualizar que si hizo el cambio en el div es como si el modal no se hubiera cerrado.

¿Como puedo hacer para que primero cierre el modal bien y despues haga el cambio en el div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré la solución a mi problema solo agregue lo siguiente a la función original

```
function ocualtar(div, page) {
$("#miModal").modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
$("#miModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(div).load(page, function (data, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            $("#errorPrincipal").html(data + "<br/>" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
            //$(div).html(data);
            finalizar();
        }
    });
});}
```